# VS Publish Profiles - Is there a way to link the application pool without setting the "IncludeIisSettings" option to true?

Tags: .net, iis, configuration, msdeploy, publish-profiles

To give some context, I'm publishing 3 web applications in the same server, and each of them uses a different application pool.

What I want to achieve, is to generate the deploy package with instructions to link the app to a specific already created application pool during the deploy.

So far, I have added the following parameters in the publish profile xml file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeAppPool>True</IncludeAppPool>
    <IncludeIisSettings>True</IncludeIisSettings>
   ...
```

In addition I have added a Parameter.xml file to the project with the parameter to set a default value for the application pool to be linked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters >
  <parameter name="Application Pool Name" description="Application Pool for this site" tags="" defaultValue="AppPoolNameXXX">
    <parameterEntry kind="DeploymentObjectAttribute"
                    scope="application"
                    match="/application/@applicationPool" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

This configuration works as expected, however, because of the IncludeIisSettings parameter, it requires to have IIS installed in the Build Continuous server (team city), and I don't like that.

My understanding (I might be completely wrong about his) is that whatever you put in the parameters file, gets applied to the archive.xml file located inside the package, which during deployment is used to set information on the installed app.

So, in the case of the application pool, if the archive.xml does not have an "application" tag, the parameter does not work, because there is nothing to overwrite.

This "application" tag right now is generated thanks to the IncludeIisSettings parameter.

Is there another way to generate this "application" tag on the archive.xml without having the IIS dependency?

Thanks in advance for your help.